# Whitelisting application properties in Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

When I create a custom app for SCDF I can, according to the [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.7.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-app-whitelisting) define relevant properties that are visible through the dashboard when creating a new stream/task. I created a `spring-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties` file like this:

```
configuration-properties.classes=com.example.MySourceProperties
configuration-properties.names=my.prop1,my.prop2
```

When I create a new stream definition through the dashboard all properties defined in `com.example.MySourceProperties` are displayed in the properties dialog, but `my.prop1` and `my.prop2` are not. Both properties aren't optional and must always be set by the user. How can I include them in the properties dialog?

Comment: could you do it properly? I tried and couldn't make it working
cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59412806/spring-cloud-data-flow-custom-application-properties

Answer (score 0):

This tells it which class to pull these properties from Task1 properties class

That we can use with "@EnableConfigurationProperties(Task1Properties.class) declaration

configuration-properties.classes=com.shifthunter.tasks.**Task1Properties**

#### Task1Properties.java

```
package com.shifthunter.tasks;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties("pulldata-task")
public class Task1Properties {

    /**
     * The path to get the source doc from
     */
    private String sourceFilePath;

    /**
     * The path to put the destination doc 
     */
    private String destinationFilePath;

    /**
     * Property to drive the exit code
     */
    private String controlMessage;

    public String getSourceFilePath() {
        return sourceFilePath;
    }

    public void setSourceFilePath(String sourceFilePath) {
        this.sourceFilePath = sourceFilePath;
    }

    public String getDestinationFilePath() {
        return destinationFilePath;
    }

    public void setDestinationFilePath(String destinationFilePath) {
        this.destinationFilePath = destinationFilePath;
    }

    public String getControlMessage() {
        return controlMessage;
    }

    public void setControlMessage(String controlMessage) {
        this.controlMessage = controlMessage;
    }
}
```

#### ShiftHunterTaskPullDataApp.java

```
package com.shifthunter.tasks;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.EnableTask;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@EnableTask
@EnableConfigurationProperties(Task1Properties.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class ShiftHunterTaskPullDataApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ShiftHunterTaskPullDataApp.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Task1 task1() {
        return new Task1();
    }

    public class Task1 implements CommandLineRunner {

        @Autowired
        private Task1Properties config;

        @Override
        public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

            System.out.println("source: " + config.getSourceFilePath());
            System.out.println("destination: " + config.getDestinationFilePath());
            System.out.println("control message: " + config.getControlMessage());

            if(config.getControlMessage().equals("fail")) {
                System.out.println("throwing an exception ...");
                throw new Exception("I'm ANGRY");
            }

            System.out.println("pulldata-task complete!");

        }
    }
}
```

#### Sream Dataflow task-pull-data

```
 app register --name task-pull-data --type task --uri maven://com.shifthunter.tasks:shifthunter-task-pulldata:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

[task-pull-data - Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLZ7H.png)