# Spring Cloud Stream App Custom Properties not showing up in Cloud Data Flow UI

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Created a processor app with custom properties. The app properties has been whitelisted. On registering the app to Spring Cloud Data Flow the custom properties are not showing up in the App Properties UI page.

```html
-------------------------------------------------
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CustomProperties.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class CustomProcessorApplication {

    @Autowired
    private CustomProperties processorProperties;

---------------------------------------------------------

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties
public class CustomProperties {

---------------------------------------------------------
Entry in src/main/resources/META-INF/dataflow-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties
configuration-properties.classes=io.spring.dataflow.file.item.CustomProperties

---------------------------------------------------------
Entry in src/main/resourcesMETA-INF/spring-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties
configuration-properties.classes=io.spring.dataflow.file.item.CustomProperties
```

Comment: Related: [Whitelisting application properties in Spring Cloud Data Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54440504) and [Spring Cloud Stream App Custom Properties not showing up in Cloud Data Flow UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64689412)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `spring-boot-configuration-processor`, e.g.,

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also, if you are using SCDF 2.6 or above, `dataflow-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties` is deprecated in favor of `dataflow-configuration-metadata.properties`.